# I need to show that $10^k \equiv -100 \bmod 1010 \iff 4\,|\, k$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, induction

> $$
> 10^k \equiv -100 \bmod1010 
> \;\iff\; 
> 4\,|\, k \text{ for all } n \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\}
> $$

I know that I need to show both directions:
$$
10^k \equiv -100 \bmod 1010 
\;\implies\; 
4\,|\, k \text{ for all } n \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\}
$$
and
$$
4\,|\, k \text{ for all } n \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\}
\;\implies\; 
10^k \equiv -100 \bmod 1010 
$$

I also think that I have proven
$$
4\,|\,n \implies 
10^k \equiv -100 \bmod1010
$$

via induction  (I'll try my best in English):

We can write:
$$
10^{4k} \equiv -100 \bmod1010
$$

Base Case:
$$
10^{4 \cdot 1} \equiv 910 \bmod 1010
$$

true ... so far so good.

Let's assume: $10^{4k} \equiv 910 \bmod 1010$

Induction step:
$$
10^{4(k+1)} 
\equiv 10^{4 \cdot k} \cdot 10^4 
\equiv 910 \cdot 10000 
\equiv 910 
\mod 1010
$$

Since that is the same rest as $-100 \bmod 1010$ it is proven .... right?

Now I need to show the other direction:

$10^k \equiv -100 \bmod 1010 \implies 4\,|\,k$

The thing is ... I don't have any idea on how to show this. Could someone here maybe help me out a bit and push me in the right direction. Thanks so much for taking the time!

Comment: Have you considered looking at $10^k+100\equiv 0 \pmod{1010}$?

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm not sure how I could use that ... How could I show that k has to be devidable by 4 with that? Maybe another hint?

Comment: Are you familiar with Chinese Remainder Theorem?

Comment: Note that some of your $4k+1$ should be $4(k+1)$ (The induction wasn't making sense to me, till I realized you had a typo).

Comment: One way to proceed by induction is to show that $ 10 ^k + 100 \equiv 110, 200, -90,0, 110, 200, -90, 0, \ldots$.

Comment: @CalvinLin But with 4(k+1) it makes sense again right?

Comment: Theoretically yes, but that assumes you fix it correctly. So it's better for you to fix it first, and then ask.

Comment: @CalvinLin I sadly don't understand what you mean with $10^k+100\equiv110$...

Comment: Factor the left-hand side and think about the prime factorization of $1010$.

Comment: Note that in your statement, $n$ isn't used anywhere, so stating that $ n \in \mathbb{N} \backslash \{0\}$ seems pointless. Do you mean $k$ instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fill in the gaps as needed. If you're stuck, state what you've tried.

**Approach 1.** Show by induction that

- $10^{4k+1}  \equiv 10 \pmod{1010}$
- $10^{4k+2} \equiv 100 \pmod{1010}$
- $10^{4k+3} \equiv -10 \pmod{1010}$
- $10^{4k+4}  \equiv -100 \pmod{1010}$
  Hence, the result follows.

Note: In my comment, I added 100 to the LHS. This presentation is easier to visually verify.

**Approach 2.** Apply Chinese remainder theorem. We want to find when

- $10^{k} \equiv 0 \pmod{10}$ -> Show that this is true iff $k \geq 1$.
- $10^k  \equiv 1 \pmod{101}$ -> Show that this is true iff $4 \mid k$.
  Hence, the result follows.

Comment: I think I would go with approach 1 since I'm not too familiar with the chinese remainder theorem yet. Could you explain tho, why those 4 inductions proof the truth of the  statement? I am super confused right now sorry. I do know how to do the 4 inductions though. I just don't understand why that proofs it.

Comment: @Crango Re "I just don't understand why that proofs it.", after proving the prior statements, we've found the value of $10^n + 100 \pmod{1010}$ for all positive integers $n$. Can you state all of the solutions to $10^n + 100 \equiv 0 \pmod{1010}$?

Comment: Wait, where do the +100 come from all of the sudden? If I calculate $10^10+100\mod1010$ for example .... it's none of the solutions we have proven. I am really sorry for getting even more confused. I'm not the fastest brain when it comes to math. To be clear, what I don't understand are the following questions: How did we find all the solutions to $10^n+100\equiv0(\mod1010)$? Why is there a + 100 all of the sudden? How did we prove via the earlier inductions that 4|n is necessary? Why did we even need to show those 4 inductions? Like where do 10,100,-10,-100 even come from?

Comment: And why are we interested in $10^{4k+x},x\in\{1,2,3,4\}$? You may notice ... I don't understand the entire concept of the second part of the proof.

Comment: I suggest you take some time to write this out yourself. Work with your version of the proof, esp if you're confused by what I wrote here.  EG Do you understand why solving for $10^n \equiv -100 \pmod{1010}$ is the same as solving for $10^n + 100 \equiv 0 \pmod{1010}$? How can we prove that $10^{4k+1} \equiv 10 \pmod{1010}$ by induction on $k$?

Comment: @Crango You don't have to accept an answer if you don't understand it. I encourage you to continue working on this, maybe come back to it when you're looking at it with fresh eyes.

Comment: Ok, I will let you know, where I end up :).

Comment: Ok, so i thought about approach one for a bit now. I think I might start to get it. Correct me if I am wrong: By showing those for inductions we can see that only on $10^{4k+4}$ we are getting our wanted congruent match of -100. Note here that the 4k+4 is the only exponent that is devidable by 4. Since all the other exponents lead us to a different congruents than -100 we have proven that k indeed must be devidable by 4. Correct? Just one quick followup question: Didn't we only show that this is true for exponents >= 5? Since the smallest number we have to show it for is 1 but here it is 5?

Comment: Because we had to show it for $10^k$ but only showed it from $10^{4*1+1}$ upwards, didn't we?

Comment: @Crango Essentially correct $\quad$ For the followup, great point. Thought note that we could have started with $k = 0 $ right? $\quad$ Sometimes, esp when $\gcd(a, n) \neq 1$, we don't have an immediately periodic sequence of remainders. That's not the case here. If that happened, we might want to check all small-enough cases and then establish the periodicity.  (I believe this happens when there is a $p$ such that $ord_p(n) > ord_p (a) \geq 1$, basically look at CRT again.)

Comment: But $0$ was excluded via definition. We said that it was for all $k\in\mathbb{N}\backslash\{0\}$. I accidentally wrote for all n in N in my post.

Comment: (Honestly you're just being very nitpicking right now and it's not conducive to understanding the bigger picture, as you're tripping yourself up) With $k= 0$ are any of $4k+1$, $4k+2$, $4k+3$, $4k+4$ equal to 0? So what is your point again? $\quad$ Even if we used $10^{4k}$, we can start with different base cases for the induction, so that we're only proving it on the positive integers.

Comment: Yes, $k$ is doing double duty in notation, being used as $k$ in the question and against as $4k$ in the induction. I generally avoid doing so because it can lead to confusion (like this) $\quad$ In this case, I was just following your solution writeup. We could use $4n+1, 4n+2, 4n+3, 4n+4$ and induct on $n$ instead, if you'd prefer.

Comment: I encourage you to write this up, make a note of any uncertainties, think about how to address them, edit it if you have any insights, post it, and then I can review your solution and provide feedback.

Comment: I really ment it more as a question. I was wondering if showing those inductions is enough or if I had to show k = 1,2,3,4 aswell ... since I didn't know. But as you pointed out ... starting with 0 on 4n+1 for example doesn't even end up with 0 anyway. I think I got everything now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

HINT.- It is equivalent to prove $$\frac{10(10^{k-2}+1)}{101}\in\mathbb N\iff 4|k$$

What I wanted to say is that the equivalent I have written has inmediate solution because $101$ is prime.