# Number of 999 digit numbers divisible by 1010 with sum of digits being 2.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

My initial try was to run a little python code just to see what those numbers would look like.

These are the first few results that match the critirea:

$1010$

$10100$

$101000$

$1010000$

$10000010$

$10100000$

$100000100$

$101000000$

$1000001000$

$1010000000$

$10000010000$

$10100000000$

So obviously the first digit has to be $1$ and then there has to be another $1$ in some other place.

The next obvious observation is that every multiple of $10$ fulfills the criteria.

The last thing I know is, that $10^k\equiv-100(\mod)\Longleftrightarrow4|k$ has something to do with it.

Other than that I am really lost in the water right now. Could anyone that has an approach push me in the right direction?
Thanks in advance!

Edit 1:

I was given the hint: $10^{998}\equiv-10^i(\mod1010)$.
Found out this is only true if $i=4k+1$.
I don't understand what to do with it though.

I also found out that if a number is devisable by $1010$ it also needs to be devisable by $101$ and $10$. Again, I don't know how to use that info yet.

Edit 2:

Trying to show that a 999 digit number with digit sum of 2 can be written as $10^{998} + 10^n$:

Not sure how to show that correctly, but I'll try my best. Say we have a 999 digit number with two $1$s in it. The first number hast to be at position 999 otherwise it would not be a 999 digit number (without leading zeros). The other $1$ can be anywhere, BUT if we take the $n$ digits of zeros behind it. We can seperate it from the 999 digit number in the format of the above statement.

Comment: Hint: it's enough to look for shorter numbers of the form $10^n+1$ which are multiples of $101$.  (Why?)

Comment: You are very close to the solution

Comment: Hint: $10^{998} \equiv - 10^i \pmod{1010}$. So, [from our work](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4721273/i-need-to-show-that-10k-equiv-100-bmod-1010-iff-4-k-for-all-n-in/4721292#4721292), what can we conclude?

Comment: @CalvinLin Well, $10^{998}\equiv100(\mod1010)$. So it also matches: $10^{4k+2}\mod 1010$. Does that help me somehow?

Comment: And so .... we want $10^ i \equiv ???$ And that means that $ i \equiv ...$ ???

Comment: @lulu Because we want to gurantee that there are exactly 2 ones? But 10001 for example doesn't match the criteria? I am sorry, I don't understand it yet :(.

Comment: $10001$ is not a multiple of $101$.

Comment: @lulu ahhh ok, sorry I missunderstood that part. Let me think about it for a few mintues.

Comment: @lulu I think i know why! Because $1010$ itself is a multiple by $101$ AND $101$ is a prime number. But how do I count them now?

Comment: @lulu Maybe somehow with prime factorizing?

Comment: You don't need to factor; keep going along the lines you were working with @CalvinLin.  As that user points out, you are nearly there.

Comment: @CalvinLin I completly missunderstood the exercise. I thought I had to add up all digit numbers that meet the criteria UNTIL 999 digit numbers. But I ONLY need to think about 999 digit numbers. For example I thought that 101000 was part of the solution. Apologies.

Comment: Can you edit your writeup to reflect the solution? We can help look over it to ensure you understood the problem.

Comment: @CalvinLin I'm still confused and trying to work out a solution. I found out that $(10^{998}+910)\mod1010=0$. Do I need to calculate how often I can add $910$ to $10^{998}$ before it swaps to $10^{999}$?

Comment: @CalvinLin Never mind. That doesn't count in the fact that the sum of digits needs to be 2.

Comment: Please edit your writeup with your current thoughts, and I can provide feedback. You seem to be easily confused over things which I feel are obvious, so I don't want to hastily comment without seeing what you are thinking.

Comment: @CalvinLin I don't have anything new though. Was thinking the last hour about the hints you and lulu gave me, trying to make sense of it. But I can't seem to connect the dots from my previous post to this one.

Comment: Please edit your writeup to reflect your thoughts, even if you think you have nothing new. EG You said "Do I need to calculate how often ..." which isn't in the writeup  $\quad$ I already gave you a suggestion for how to proceed, but you don't seem to understand / care about it. Given how you responded to my previous solution, there are several steps which I take for granted that you don't seem to have understood as yet. That is why I NEED you to write stuff up so that I can understand what you are thinking, especially if you're not on the right track.

Comment: @CalvinLin updated. Sorry, didn't think this was important if I hadn't found out anything new.

Comment: It is important. It gives me a sense of where you're at. EG It seems to me that you need to be told every step of a solution, and can't figure out what the next/prior steps could be.  $\quad$ Can you: show that a 999 digit number with digit sum of 2 can be written as $ 10^{998} + 10^n$, where $ 0 \leq n \leq 998$

Comment: @CalvinLin Updated. Edit 2.

Comment: How do these statement relate to each other? What other conclusions can you draw? Is this enough to prove the problem? If no, what is missing?

Comment: @CalvinLin I don't know. I feel like there is some modular arithmetic rule I am missing that would give me the solution. I just can't see the connection here.

Comment: @CalvinLin Btw. pls don't think that I am too lazy to think about this ... I legit have been sitting here for three hours now trying to solve this.

Comment: That is literally all that you need, and you just have to connect the dots. There is no (negligible) further calculation that is needed, it has all been done. Like I said "It seems to me that you need to be told every step of a solution, and can't figure out what the next/prior steps could be." $\quad$ I don't think you're lazy. I have seen you put in the work, and I know it can be frustrating to be stuck, which is why I'm walking you through it when you demonstrate the work / what you are doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Show the following. Fill in the blanks as needed.

1. A 999 digit number with digit sum of 2 can be written as $ 10^{998} + 10^n$, where $ 0 \leq n \leq 998$.
2. Show that $10^{998} \equiv \underline{\quad} \pmod{1010}$. Hence, show that $ 10^{998} + 10^n \equiv 0 \pmod{1010}$ iff $10^n \equiv \underline{910 \equiv -100} \pmod{1010}$ iff $  n \equiv \underline{0} \pmod{\underline{4}}$
3. There are $\underline{249}$ values of $ 0 \leq n \leq 998$ that satisfy the above condition.
4. There are $\underline{249}$ 999 digit numbers with a digit sum of 2 that are a multiple of 1010.

Recall that

- $10^{4k+1}  \equiv 10 \pmod{1010}$
- $10^{4k+2} \equiv 100 \pmod{1010}$
- $10^{4k+3} \equiv -10 \pmod{1010}$
- $10^{4k+4}  \equiv -100 \pmod{1010}$

Comment: Blank1 = 910, Blank2 = 0, Blank3 = 4. Right?

Comment: Yup. $\quad \quad$

Comment: What I don't quiet get is how you got there. How did you know without a calculator that $n$ needs to be devidable by $4$? Still thinking about Blank4 and 5 btw.

Comment: Because of the "recall that $10^{4k+4} \equiv - 100 \equiv 910 \pmod{1010}$".  It is literally the same question (ignoring the condition on 999 digit number). Are you saying that you still don't understand the previous question? $\quad$ Do you agree that A/ If $10^n \equiv 910 \pmod{1010}$ then $ n \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$?  B/ If $ n \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$ then $ 10^n \equiv 910 \pmod{1010}$? Thus we have "iff".

Comment: Yeah, I still don't get it. It is just hopeless in my eyes. I just don't understand what information $-100\mod1010=910$ gives you, that lets you solve the question in the title. In my brain everything is completly unrelated.

Comment: Yeah, I understand how you get from $10^n \equiv 910 (\mod 1010)$ to $n \equiv 0 (\mod 4)$. The part I don't understand is the first part.

Comment: Do you agree and understand the following statements? If yes, provide a short explanation why it is true (EG By definition, induction, obvious, etc) $\quad$ 1/ $-100 \equiv 910 \pmod{1010}$. 2/ $10^{4k+4} \equiv -100 \pmod{1010}$. 3/ $10^{4k+4} \equiv 910 \pmod{1010}$. 4/ $10^{4k+1} \not \equiv -100 \pmod{1010}$.

Comment: I understand all 4 statements. I just can't make the connection to the 999 digit question.

Comment: Great! K, so going back to my writeup. I just added numbers to the statements. You currently agree with statements 1 and 2 right? Do you understand how to prove those 2 separate statements? (EG You said "How did you know without a calculator that $n$ needs to be devidable by 4", which made me think you didn't understand it at all.)

Comment: To be very specific what I don't understand: $10^{998} + 10 ^{n} \equiv 0 (\mod 1010)$ iff n is devisable by 4. ... LIke with a calculator I can make that connectiont too. But how did you make it without one.

Comment: But you said you understood all 4 statements previously. That is what it established. It didn't need a calculator (I'm assuming you can calculate $910 \times 10 \pmod{1010}$ without having to resort to a calculator). What did you need a calculator for? $\quad$ **Please provide a short explanation for why each of the 4 statements is true**.

Comment: I literally calculated $10^{998} + 10^n \mod 1010$, ok let me try to explain the 4.

Comment: How did you do that? For all n? Also, at no point were you asked to calculate that.

Comment: I only needed to calculate till 5, since it repeats itself. No, but I tried to figure out what the blanks were.

Comment: Without using a calculator, can you explain why it repeats itself every 4 terms (so repeat on the 5th)? You may use existing calculations that we have done before.

Comment: This one I could solve manually. It's 10. But I dont know how to solve the big number one. $10^{998} + 10^n \mod 1010$

Comment: I asked "why does it repeat every 4 terms" and you say "it's 10".  I don't know how to interpret that. $\quad$ You're not expressing yourself clearly. You say one thing, but happen to mean something else, and yet refuse to provide me with enough information to make a determination.

Comment: I've got to go for now. Read through the above, and 1/ Provide a short explanation for why each of the 4 statements in the comment is true, 2/ Explain why $10^{998} \equiv 100 \pmod{1010}$, 3/ work through statement 2 in the solution sin the previous (and ideally WITHOUT using a calculator).

Comment: Ok, so 1/ is true because -100 and 910 are 1010 appart, so they have the same rest when devided by 1010. I know 2/ is true because I have done an induction for it. 3/ is True because 1/ and 2/ are true, a bit like transitivity. To show 4/ is not true I could do an induction to show that, but I know how to do that.
For the second assignment. I actually don't know how to do that in my head. So yeah, there is one problem. Will do third assignment now.

Comment: For the second assignment again: I do know how to calculate $100 \mod 1010$ in my head but not $10^{998} \mod 1010$.

Comment: I finally understood 2.) in your write up! Except for the $10^{998} \mod 1010$, calculated in brain part. ... we are saying that $10^{998}$ has a rest, congruent to 910. Then we add that rest on top of $10^{998}$ to achieve a rest of $0$! That can be done with $10^n$ which has the sideaffect of achieving the digit sum of $2$. Only if $10^n$ is congruent to $10^{998}$ of course, which it is when n is devisable by 4. Brain is smoking now, need to sleep. Will think about 3 and 4 in your write up tomorrow.

Comment: 4 is true because $10^{4k+1} \equiv 10$ (which can be shown by induction), and $10 \not \equiv \pmod{1010}$, so by transitivity, $ 10^{4k+1} \not \equiv -100 \pmod{1010}$. $\quad$ Likewise, we can show that $10^{4k+2 } \equiv 100 \not \equiv -100 \pmod{1010}$ and $10^{4k+3} \equiv -10 \not equiv -100 \pmod{100}$.  $\quad$ For the second assignment, as a further hint, what is $ 998 \pmod{4}$? How does that tell us what is $10^{998} \pmod{1010}$ without using a calculator? $\quad$ For the third assignment, that's mostly correct, though you're missing some negative signs.(cont)

Comment: We have $ 10 ^{998} + 10^n \equiv 0 0\pmod{1010} $ iff $\color{red}{-}  10 ^ { 998 } \equiv 10^n \pmod{1010}$. Since $10^{998} \equiv 100 \pmod{1010}$ (assuming this for now), so this is equivalent to saying $-100 \equiv 10^n \pmod{1010}$. This is equivalent to $n = 4k+4$, or that $ n \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$.

Comment: $998 \mod 4 = 2$, therefore we know that $10^{998}$ is congruent to $10^{4k+2}$. I am going to make another explanation for your second comment, could you correct it if I am wrong please? (cont)

Comment: Ok, we have $10^{998} \mod 1010 = 100$, but we want to cancel that rest out to $0$, so we need to add something that is congruent to $(-100 \mod 1010)$, because, the rest of  $(-100 \mod 1010)$ cancles the rest of  $(100 \mod 1010)$ out. (right?)  Which can be $(10^n)$ iff $(n \mod4 = 0)$. Is that also a valid explanation?

Comment: As for $3$ and $4$ in your write up. The correct answer is $249$. Correct? Because $998$ devided by $4$ is 249.5.

Comment: Right, looking at the exponent mod the periodicity, we can evaluate $10^{998} \equiv 10^2 \pmod{1010}$ without massive calculation. This is the idea behind Fermat's Little Theorem / Euler's Theorem.   $\quad$ Yes, that's the right idea with $10^{998}$. Ideally you get comfortable with it over time, and can write $ 0 \equiv 10^{998} + 10^n \equiv 100 + 10^n \Rightarrow 10^n \equiv -100$. Part of the power of modular arithmetic is that the language makes it easy for you to express ideas, but it does require knowledge/understanding/comfortability with it.  $\quad$ Yes, 249.

Comment: Yeah I literally just startet with modular arithmetic, but I am sure I will get there. You helped me understand a lot of core concepts here. Thank you so much! I'll dive a bit into chinese remainder theorem now, let's see what that'll bring me.

Comment: @Crango It would have been helpful to explain that you literally just started with modular arithmetic, esp when you saw us (lulu, etc) jumping really far ahead / skipping steps from your perspective.    $\quad$ I suggest that you build up your foundation a bit more, so that several of these steps are more natural to you (EG You were unfamiliar with simplifying large exponentiation using Euler's Theorem, and you only toolkit was manual calculation)  It does take some practice to get familiar with the ideas of a new concept.

Comment: True, I am also new to this platfrom, so I definitely need to improve my asking skills aswell.